# Duplicate all rows n times but change one column value each time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table in SQL such as the following:

| Porfolio_num | Sim_num | SECID | FV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |

I'd like to duplicate it 5 times, each time incrementing the values in columns `Portfolio_num` and `Sim_num` by one.

The desired outcome is:

| Portfolio_num | Sim_num | SECID | FV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 0 | 0 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |
| 1 | 1 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 1 | 1 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 1 | 1 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |
| 2 | 2 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 2 | 2 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 2 | 2 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |
| 3 | 3 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 3 | 3 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 3 | 3 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |
| 4 | 4 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 4 | 4 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 4 | 4 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |
| 5 | 5 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 5 | 5 | TB20230521 | 38,000 |
| 5 | 5 | TB20230621 | 40,000 |

Query to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    Portfolio_num int,
    Sim_num int,
    SECID varchar(10),
    FV int
)
INSERT INTO test (Portfolio_num, Sim_num, SECID, FV)

VALUES

(0,0, 'TB20230421', 34000),
(0,0, 'TB20230521', 38000),
(0,0, 'TB20230621', 40000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PortfolioData;

CREATE TABLE #PortfolioData (
    Porfolio_num INT,
    Sim_num INT,
    SECID VARCHAR(10),
    FV MONEY
);

INSERT INTO #PortfolioData (Porfolio_num, Sim_num, SECID, FV)
VALUES
    (0, 0, 'TB20230421', 34000),
    (0, 0, 'TB20230521', 38000),
    (0, 0, 'TB20230421', 40000);

SELECT DS.[n] AS [Porfolio_num]
      ,DS.[N] AS [Sim_num]
      ,PD.[SECID]
      ,PD.[FV]
FROM #PortfolioData PD
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (6) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) -1
    FROM master..spt_values
) DS (n)
ORDER BY DS.[n]
```

[image]

In the cross apply we are just generating a data source with X rows (you can adjust it to your real needs).

Answer (score 1):

How about a cross join:

```sql
SELECT
    t2.num AS Portfolio_num,
    t2.num AS Sim_num,
    t1.SECID,
    t1.FV
FROM test t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 5
) t2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

You may replace the subquery aliased as `t2` with a bona fide sequence table.